# Could you submerge any electronic device (with no applied power) and see no ill effects?

Tags: power, water

In theory, could you completely submerge an electronic device in water, let it *fully* dry out, apply power, and see no ill effects?

**My logic:** I can't see how how you wouldn't be able to do this. I understand capacitors and batteries hold charges, but if removed, they shouldn't be affected? Water damages components by shorting circuits and causing too much current and destroying components.

I am a curious senior in Electrical Engineering, so feel free to use big words or big insults in your explanation. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes in fact some assembly processes wash boards coming off the assembly line.  Can you wash everything?   No.  Someone may correct me but if I remember right electrolytic caps for example can absorb water.   Things like switches may trap water or oxidize and corrode contacts when that standing water gets left on there.   Pretty sure electret mics don't like it nor would speakers and qfns often trap water for days.

But I'd say in general fully discharged and unpowered, then fully dried and perhaps baked it should work again.

Look at this thing it's basically an overgrown board [dishwasher](https://www.manncorp.com/pcb-and-stencil-cleaning/pcb-stencil-cleaning-defluxing-machine/trident-zdo-zero-discharge-aqueous-pcb-cleaner.html) :)

[image]

Comment: I teach a lab where students solder together boards for a small robot. The beepers on the boards come with stickers that say "remove after washing". It's fun to see the look on students' faces when they think they have to wash their robots.

Comment: Wonderful! I thought this might be the case. Seems simple enough!

Comment: Because the parts that can become internally water-fouled (haha) are often thru-hole parts, some manufacturing processes will do all the SMT parts, then wash the board, then send the board to a hand-soldering station for the last few thru-hole parts. If you open manufactured electronics, sometimes you will see this, evidenced by flux residue on the thru-hole parts at the board edges (connectors, switches, etc.) but nowhere else.

Comment: That is also done to avoid the need for a wave soldering line if the through hole component count is small enough.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is assuming you mean like fully built electronic devices.

Yes in-fact you can, however the proper care must be taken after the incident. 
A Company called TekDry makes a device that drys electronics. If you don't plug it in you can most likely send it to them. They say its 80% chance and they don't charge you if it doesn't work.